# Could anyone help me solve this correlogram econometrics question?

Tags: time-series, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Given Equation
$$\LARGE\varepsilon_t=\delta\varepsilon_{t-1}+u_t$$

How would I work out the correlogram for this AR(1) error processes?

$E(e_t,x_t)=0$
$E(e_0)=0$, and
$u_t$ is white noise process i.e. $E(u_t)=0$, $E(u_{t^2})=\sigma^2$, $E(u_t,u_s)=0$.

Also how would I show that $E(e_t)=0$?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: You attempted to include two images, but only one shows because you for got the image link! Anyhow, it is better (and expected of you) to type formulas using $\LaTeX$, and not by including images!